# jquery & php color every other row

Tags: php, foreach, colors, html-table, row

I want to make every other colored on my table here.
I have think about some jquery but I don't know what is best practice.. I hope some one can help me.

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><i>Overskrift</i></td>
        <td><i>Antal svar</i></td>
        <td><i>Sidste svar af</i></td>
        <td><i>Dato</i></td>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($activeQuery as $activeThread): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>forum/post/<?php echo $activeThread->traadID; ?>">
        <?php echo $activeThread->traadOverskrift; ?></td>
        <td><?php ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activeThread->kommentareBrugernavn; ?></td>
        <td><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $activeThread->kommentareDato; ?>">
        <?php echo $activeThread->kommentareDato; ?></abbr></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `nth-child()` selector is a better choice for this case

```
$("tr:nth-child(even)").css("backgroundColor", "#bbbbff");
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Thanks so much i have use your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:even` and/or `:odd` selector

```
$("tr:gt(0):even td").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

or

```
$("tr:gt(0):odd td").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Comment: Thanks so much i will look at the selector you have linked but i have use @Jose solution :)